# Refer to a specific index of an array depending on user input

Tags: c#, arrays, string, sorting

Trying to make a program where it takes in an equation from user and outputs the answer. Having to develop all code for it to work, and wondering how I could refer to either array index value either side of a specific index?

**Example:
User input: X = 5 + 5 * 6**

Wanting to be able to locate the ***** and retrieve the value of the **5** & **6** either side of it. Tried multiple things and tried searching here too, cannot find a answer.

Thankyou in advance to anyone who takes the time to help!

Comment: You should use [Recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). Google it. There many samples in the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to use regular expressions. I would remove all whitespaces first to make it easier. For example:

```
string input = "X = 5 + 5 * 6";
Regex r = new Regex(@"(\d+)\*(\d+)");
Match m = r.Match(input.Replace(" ", ""));
var a = m.Groups[1].Value; // a = 5
var b = m.Groups[2].Value; // b = 6
```

Explanation of this regex can be found here:  https://regex101.com/r/k7rthI/1

You would have to improve the regex to handle decimals and many other cases when the equation gets more complex. It is a long dark rabbit hole to go down if you get more complex than what you have. So you might be better off finding a math library you can use. No reason to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot for your quick reply, I will try this/look into the regex. I wish I could use a math library, but this is a school task and we are not allowed for libraries..

Comment: First time for me posting on SO, am I able to leave it in case anyone else has any suggestions? Cheers mate.